# How to use MATLAB inside Jupyter?

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter

I seem to have installed everything right. I can run disp('statement') in jupyter. The kernel box is showing Matlab.

but still in Jupyter I get

```
import matlab.engine
```

Error:

```
The import statement 'import matlab.engine' cannot be found or cannot be imported. Imported names must end with '.*' or be fully qualified.
```

on the MATLAB side, inside my conda environment, I am able to get into a Python 3.6 command line and execute

```
import matlab.engine
```

That means I got the MATLAB-Python integration working.

I did

```
python -m matlab_kernel install --user
```

and

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

shows

```
  matlab     /home/me/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/matlab
  python2    /home/me/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3    /home/me/anaconda3/envs/matlab/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

with no problem.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured it out.

the notebook is either running in Ipython mode or Matlab mode. I was in Matlab mode, and trying out tutorial code for Ipython mode.